# How to set media queries and make them working on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want my font size to change when the browser resizes as well as on mobile. If I try to do it on PC this code works, but if I open my site on mobile it doesn't resize my text.

I'm asking why this code isn't working, not how write it.

Html (about the stylesheet; the one for mobile is the "handheld.css"):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1121px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handheld.css" media="only screen and (max-width:1120px)">
```

handheld.css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:321px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 16px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width:380px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 17px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:420px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 27px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 18px;
    }
}

#easy{
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  font-family: "sweetness", Verdana;
    top: -63%;
    margin-left: 3px;
                                       fontsize: calc(15px + 3vw);\\this is an alternative to media queries
}

h2{ 
  position: relative;
  color:#fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: "sweetness", Verdana;
   text-shadow:
   -0.5px -0.5px 0 #000,  
    0.5px -0.5px 0 #000,
    -0.5px 0.5px 0 #000,
     0.5px 0.5px 0 #000;
     top: 40px;
                                         fontsize: calc(15px + 2vw); \\this is an alternative to media queries

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: @n_palum I wrote that the code isn't working, not how to do it!

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi: is this just an example? It doesn't make sense to increment font size by 1px...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules order is that *master* (default) rules should come first. They define default styles. And second "section" contains media queries. Thus you just need to move last two classes to the begin of the stylesheet. In your case they override all rules defined by media queries.

Here is a solution:

```css
#easy{
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  font-family: "sweetness", Verdana;
    top: -63%;
    margin-left: 3px;
                                       fontsize: calc(15px + 3vw);\\this is an alternative to media queries
}

h2{ 
  position: relative;
  color:#fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: "sweetness", Verdana;
   text-shadow:
   -0.5px -0.5px 0 #000,  
    0.5px -0.5px 0 #000,
    -0.5px 0.5px 0 #000,
     0.5px 0.5px 0 #000;
     top: 40px;
                                         fontsize: calc(15px + 2vw); \\this is an alternative to media queries

}
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:379px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 16px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width:419px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 17px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:420px) {
    #easy {
        font-size: 27px;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Comment: also if in my css there aren't  the default fontsizes in the two elements ? I'll try it now.

Comment: I noticed one more issue: this `@media only screen and (min-width:420px)` will always override default settings for screens above 420px

Comment: I've changed the answer min-width replaced with corresponding max-width